# How to parse a text file into variables and a list

Tags: python

I have a text file which looks like:

```
2.34 5.32 4.3 [1, 6,-5, 112] other stuff
12.11 5.3 1.93 [11, -6, 55, -12] other stuff
```

That is each line has three floating point numbers followed by a list and after the list there is some other stuff. I would like to read it in a line at a time and get the three floating point numbers and the  list in four different variables.  I can get all the lines with:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

But I don't know how to then go through the lines and extract the floating point numbers and the list.

```
for line in lines:
    a, b, c, list_of_integers = parse(line)  # How can you implement parse?
    # do something with a, b, c, list_of_integers


def parse(line):
    # ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
def parse(line):
    p1, p2 = line.split('[', 1)
    p2 = p2.split(']', 1)[0]
    a, b, c = [float(n) for n in p1.strip().split()]
    list_of_integers = [int(n) for n in p2.split(',')]
    return a, b, c, list_of_integers

with open("test.txt", "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        a, b, c, list_of_integers = parse(line)
        print(a, b, c, list_of_integers)
```

Output:

```
2.34 5.32 4.3 [1, 6, -5, 112]
12.11 5.3 1.93 [11, -6, 55, -12]
```

Comment: I think you should `return` the variables rather than printing them.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had tried to use ast.literal_eval but with no luck

Comment: @quamrana. I did it

Comment: You don't need `ast.literal_eval` here.